# prototype.js1.6.1 getElementsByTagName null value in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, prototypejs

```
  getElements: function(form) {
  console.log(form);
var elements = $(form).getElementsByTagName('*'), //problem point
    element,
    arr = [ ],
    serializers = Form.Element.Serializers;
console.log("elements:"+elements);
console.log("arr:"+arr);
console.log("serializers:"+serializers);
for (var i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) {     // not working
  arr.push(element);
}
return arr.inject([], function(elements, child) {
  if (serializers[child.tagName.toLowerCase()])
    elements.push(Element.extend(child));
  return elements;
})
```

},

in IE 7,8,9 working 
but in chrome and IE10 case **elements value was null (i tried console.log(elements[0]);)**
image is my console log

what should i do?
please help me gentleman.

![
please click error button.

][error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AXCr.png)

Below is a prototype.js 1.7.1 version

```
  getElements: function(form) {
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var elements = $(form).getElementsByTagName('*'); 
if(is_chrome){
    var elements = $(form).select('*');     //still problem in chrome
    console.log(elements.length);
}
var element, results = [], serializers = Form.Element.Serializers;
for (var i = 0; element = elements[i]; i++) {
  if (serializers[element.tagName.toLowerCase()])
    results.push(Element.extend(element));
}
return results;
```

},

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use prototypejs?

Comment: Instead of `$(form).getElementsByTagName('*')` have you tried `$(form).select('*')` ?

Comment: Really thanks!!! your comments but... $(form).select('*') was same result.

Comment: $(form) values exist I think getElementsByTagName method problem

Comment: t.niese// Yes i fixed some large source for multi browsing. but that source  already used prototypejs. Anyway changing jquery is impossible situation

Comment: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/getElements/

Comment: james emanon// thanks api. I Reference it during solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I catch the problem

getElementsByTagName method need correct tag using
(Working in ie9 below version but, ie10 ,chrome,FF etc do not working)

check your tag!